# Jrebel ERR_UNKNOWN failure?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, deployment, glassfish, jrebel

Jrebel ERR_UNKNOWN failure?

- Eclipse Version:**Kepler**
- Java Version:**JDK(1.6.0_32)**
- JRebel Version:**JRebel 5.3.1**
- Glassfish Version:**Glassfish 3.1**

### Jrebel.log

```
2013-07-20 14:59:06.557 INFO  [Remoting] Raw headers: {connection=Keep-Alive, x-rebel-id=a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3, host=localhost:8080, x-rebel-request=true, content-length=0, x-rebel-signature=3c3607a8c599cf467b5b9d0ecad9dbbf5ccdbae49ccba5517017629a4536c20482a5612bd3f4e655a3397e89d59f7f412b71af49cf81601fec4bc70385d0690d1dd5ed697b12d7af7474e3b3b140fec7c83dd2298de1f869ef3bb706576915864c3be029f3e7bb5ceda319bd9727062ce33c6dc515db9452ae92f4c8b4b58cd4, user-agent=Apache-HttpClient/4.1.2 (java 1.5)}
2013-07-20 14:59:06.557 INFO  [Remoting] Searching RemotingApp by hash: a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
2013-07-20 14:59:06.557 INFO  [Remoting] Performing handshake
2013-07-20 14:59:06.557 INFO  [Remoting] Rebel hash: a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
2013-07-20 14:59:06.557 INFO  [Remoting] Signature: 3c3607a8c599cf467b5b9d0ecad9dbbf5ccdbae49ccba5517017629a4536c20482a5612bd3f4e655a3397e89d59f7f412b71af49cf81601fec4bc70385d0690d1dd5ed697b12d7af7474e3b3b140fec7c83dd2298de1f869ef3bb706576915864c3be029f3e7bb5ceda319bd9727062ce33c6dc515db9452ae92f4c8b4b58cd4
2013-07-20 14:59:06.557 INFO  [Remoting] Error - Signature is not valid!!!
2013-07-20 14:59:06.557 ERROR [Remoting] org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.endpoint.RemotingException: Handshake encountered an exception
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.endpoint.requests.HandshakeRequest.execute(HandshakeRequest.java:67)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.endpoint.RemotingRequestHandler.execute(RemotingRequestHandler.java:139)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.endpoint.RemotingRequestListener.rawRequest(RemotingRequestListener.java:29)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xe.a(JRebel:112)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xe.fireRawRequest(JRebel:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.endpoint.RemotingException: Supplied signature is not valid for remoting module ' a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3' (public and private keys don't match).
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.endpoint.requests.HandshakeRequest.execute(HandshakeRequest.java:61)
    ... 22 more

2013-07-20 14:59:06.557 INFO  [Remoting] Writing response headers: {x-rebel-response=ERR_UNKNOWN, x-rebel-responseMessage=Handshake encountered an exception}
2013-07-20 14:59:06.557 INFO  [Remoting] Setting header x-rebel-response = ERR_UNKNOWN
2013-07-20 14:59:06.557 INFO  [Remoting] Setting header x-rebel-responseMessage = Handshake encountered an exception
2013-07-20 14:59:06.557 INFO  [Core-SDK] Request listener org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.endpoint.RemotingRequestListener@d25e28 fully managed a request
    2013-07-20 19:12:18.844 INFO  [Remoting] normal GET request: 'http://localhost:8080/test1/'. Ignoring it and allowing it to proceed
2013-07-20 19:12:48.723 INFO  [Remoting] Received remoting request: http://localhost:8080/test1/
2013-07-20 19:12:48.723 INFO  [Remoting] Raw headers: {connection=Keep-Alive, x-rebel-id=b444ac06613fc8d63795be9ad0beaf55011936ac, host=localhost:8080, x-rebel-request=true, content-length=0, x-rebel-signature=66dbf071cf949e898caf8efc01a3bbbcaa2d7919ceab92be8b3236f71e01e5f3b111e89a5cffe3c77ee5e100723d31d91cf5ace7f945f957a99e9d480d05735e4be42c4cc71b0e31a71123087801f94f4b3b78fc33d4b1a1abb57a14758368c5b9f36076a845da0a3c738c75c8486101b4c7e00c7e5581e9dc5148b31d0ba1fb, user-agent=Apache-HttpClient/4.1.2 (java 1.5)}
2013-07-20 19:12:48.724 INFO  [Remoting] Searching RemotingApp by hash: b444ac06613fc8d63795be9ad0beaf55011936ac
2013-07-20 19:12:48.724 INFO  [Remoting] Performing handshake
2013-07-20 19:12:48.724 INFO  [Remoting] Rebel hash: b444ac06613fc8d63795be9ad0beaf55011936ac
2013-07-20 19:12:48.724 INFO  [Remoting] Signature: 66dbf071cf949e898caf8efc01a3bbbcaa2d7919ceab92be8b3236f71e01e5f3b111e89a5cffe3c77ee5e100723d31d91cf5ace7f945f957a99e9d480d05735e4be42c4cc71b0e31a71123087801f94f4b3b78fc33d4b1a1abb57a14758368c5b9f36076a845da0a3c738c75c8486101b4c7e00c7e5581e9dc5148b31d0ba1fb
2013-07-20 19:12:48.725 INFO  [Remoting] Signature is valid, generating symmetric key and encrypting it
2013-07-20 19:12:48.727 INFO  [Remoting] Handshake successful
2013-07-20 19:12:48.727 INFO  [Remoting] Writing response headers: {x-rebel-response=HANDSHAKE_OK, x-rebel-key=62ab3d875685bf6ec481b177c1cc422bd1c29e362f57ccbcef8302a61f073f1f903074336c81147e6a6e701e424f39152d91aefacdf16f8a2fa5ba6b5e03dbf5db6e6cc3fdf9a0819740d6922af90a6899f9f390145f53420d84e96ff53c270fdeece99222c3b53bf401b101a0b9a55592a82081103c79a75d85d5a49fdf54f7}
2013-07-20 19:12:48.727 INFO  [Remoting] Setting header x-rebel-response = HANDSHAKE_OK
2013-07-20 19:12:48.728 INFO  [Remoting] Setting header x-rebel-key = 62ab3d875685bf6ec481b177c1cc422bd1c29e362f57ccbcef8302a61f073f1f903074336c81147e6a6e701e424f39152d91aefacdf16f8a2fa5ba6b5e03dbf5db6e6cc3fdf9a0819740d6922af90a6899f9f390145f53420d84e96ff53c270fdeece99222c3b53bf401b101a0b9a55592a82081103c79a75d85d5a49fdf54f7
2013-07-20 19:12:48.728 INFO  [Core-SDK] Request listener org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.endpoint.RemotingRequestListener@124e57b fully managed a request


   2013-07-20 19:12:48.767 INFO  [Remoting] Received remoting request: http://localhost:8080/test1/
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.768 INFO  [Remoting] Raw headers: {connection=Keep-Alive, x-rebel-id=b444ac06613fc8d63795be9ad0beaf55011936ac, host=localhost:8080, x-rebel-request=true, content-length=0, user-agent=Apache-HttpClient/4.1.2 (java 1.5), x-rebel-headers=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}
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.768 INFO  [Remoting] Searching RemotingApp by hash: b444ac06613fc8d63795be9ad0beaf55011936ac
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.768 INFO  [Remoting] Decrypted headers: {x-rebel-sessionıd=Eclipse 2013-07-20 18:07:11.021, x-rebel-remotingversion=2, x-rebel-id=test1, x-rebel-deploymentıd=, x-rebel-transaction=begin}
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.768 INFO  [Remoting] Starting transaction
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.768 INFO  [Remoting] Rolling back transaction transaction-2013.07.20-19.10.58.292
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.768 INFO  [Remoting] Starting new transaction. id=transaction-2013.07.20-19.12.48.762
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.768 INFO  [Remoting] Sync needed
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.768 INFO  [Remoting] Writing hash codes
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.768 INFO  [Remoting] Writing classpath hashes
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.768 INFO  [Remoting] f5afcee4195e9a9de7fc872036ff7207 rebel.xml
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.768 INFO  [Remoting] 843fef4670978ddbc093a79c149533ac rebel-remote.xml
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.768 INFO  [Remoting] Writing web hashes
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.768 INFO  [Remoting] 696a66c71a7a50dd21ea55e6124b3eb9 index.jsp
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.768 INFO  [Remoting] 0b28d96f3aa51b06027dab5c3d04c149 WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.768 INFO  [Remoting] 4e6c194140f6c4c37281282e081d01c2 WEB-INF/web.xml
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.769 INFO  [Remoting] b10f37c8bb1803d98c127a01d1a71cc5 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.769 INFO  [Remoting] Successfully wrote hash codes
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.769 INFO  [Remoting] Writing response headers: {x-rebel-response=SYNC_NEEDED, x-rebel-deploymentId=test1 2013-07-20 19:10:13.656, x-rebel-transactionId=transaction-2013.07.20-19.12.48.762}
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.769 INFO  [Remoting] Setting header x-rebel-headers
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.769 INFO  [Remoting] Writing response body. Length: 236
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.769 INFO  [Remoting] Encrypting response body
    2013-07-20 19:12:48.769 INFO  [Core-SDK] Request listener org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.endpoint.RemotingRequestListener@124e57b fully managed a request
```

Jrebel error log

### Console Error

```
Starting synchronization for project: test
Refreshing project test...
Directory /WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/ will be used for uploading
Directory /test-classes/ will be used for uploading
Directory /WebContent/ will be used for uploading
Connecting to http://localhost:8080/test/
ERR_UNKNOWN
```

console error log

### domains\domain1\Domain.xml

```
<java-config debug-options="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009" system-classpath="" classpath-suffix="">
        <jvm-options>-XX:MaxPermSize=192m</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-client</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Djavax.management.builder.initial=com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AppServerMBeanServerBuilder</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/modules/endorsed${path.separator}${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/endorsed</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Djava.security.policy=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/server.policy</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Djava.security.auth.login.config=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/login.conf</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Xmx512m</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/keystore.jks</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/cacerts.jks</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Djava.ext.dirs=${com.sun.aas.javaRoot}/lib/ext${path.separator}${com.sun.aas.javaRoot}/jre/lib/ext${path.separator}${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/lib/ext</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/modules/autostart/</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-XX:NewRatio=2</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-javaagent:F:\\eclipsek\\eclipse\\plugins\\org.zeroturnaround.eclipse.embedder_5.3.1.RELEASE-201307081557\\jrebel\\jrebel.jar</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Drebel.properties=C:\\Users\\HP\\.jrebel\\jrebel.properties</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Drebel.log.file=C:\\Users\\HP\\.jrebel\\jrebel.log</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Drebel.workspace.path=C:\\Users\\HP\\workspace-kepler</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Drebel.remoting_plugin=true</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Drebel.notification.url=http://127.0.0.1:4672/jrebel/notifications</jvm-options>
      </java-config>
```

**What error solution?**

Answer (score 0):

In the exception stack trace it says, "public and private keys don't match". You have a public key defined in the **rebel-remote.xml** but your signature that comes from the IDE is invalid. You either remove the keys for good or regenerate rebel-remote.xml with the new keys.